# Json_decode returning Null and Error 4

Tags: java, php, json, laravel

I'm getting null when I decode my Json. $contactInfo is a String from Java(Android) pushed via Volley. I did check the string, it is a string.

I have tried the following

1) Make the $contactInfo with one user's contact only

2) Removed spaces

3) Remove special characters like  ♡

4) Remove +

**The closest solution I can find to reading such [[data,data],[data,data]] is to use json decode. Is there any other way for me to read this into a array or json?**

```
$contactInfo = "[[john qiu, +16266169643], [Vince, +65 5888 8447]]"
$obj = stripslashes($contactInfo);
$obj = json_decode($obj);
echo json_last_error();
```

echo is returning JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX

contactInfo, for some users , there are special characters like "♡"

Comment: Where is `$data`, the error is pretty self-explanatory.  It isn't valid JSON syntax.  `[[john qiu, +1626643]]` isn't valid JSON if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: @Devon The closest solution I can find to reading such [[data,data],[data,data]] is to use json decode. Is there any other way for me to read this into a array or json?

Comment: Where are you getting this data from?  There are certainly other ways, but it'd probably just be easier to address the format of the data at the source.

Comment: `[[john qiu, +1626643]]` is not a valid JSON `{[john qiu, +1626643]}` should be. Can u dump the whole string you are getting returned, and tell us if the form is always the same, maybe we can figure out a function to decode it.

Comment: @PawelBieszczad I tried hard coding {[john qiu, +1626643]}. I have updated the "whole dump" I received

Comment: @Devon I'm using Android Volley Post Request to my API. I'm forced to convert the Arraylist.toString() before i send it out to my api.

Comment: @Devon string have to be wrappen in double quotes for a valid json format. Can you change the way your java app is returning the data? otherwise we will have to use some dirty way of decoding this string, prone to bugs

Comment: Also, the integer (I assume) cannot have the `+` sign in front of it.

Comment: @PawelBieszczad Removed that too. doesnt work

Comment: `$contactInfo = '[["john qiu", 16266169643], ["Vince", 6558888447]]"` doesnt work?

Comment: @PawelBieszczad Would you like to write your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The correct JSON format is

```
$contactInfo = '[["john qiu", 16266169643], ["Vince", 6558888447]]"
```

You can validate your output, to see if its right on some website like [this](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) one for example

Answer (score 0):

How about this code

```
$contactInfo = "[[john qiu, +1626643]]";
$obj = json_decode($contactInfo, true);
var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: Nope :( Getting null still

Answer (score 0):

```
$contactInfo = "[[john qiu, +16266169643], [Vince, +65 5888 8447]]"
```

In PHP, above $contactInfo itself is an array. To avoid any error, please ensure the non-numeric values are in quotes. eg:

```
$contactInfo = "[['john qiu', '+16266169643'], ['Vince', '+65 5888 8447']]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole string should be wrapped in single quotes allowing you to encapsulate the json string segments in double quotes

```
<?php
$contactInfo = '[["john qiu", "+16266169643"], ["Vince", "+65 5888 8447"]]';
json_decode($contactInfo, true);
echo json_last_error(); 
?>
<b>output 0</b>
```

If your data doesn't come formatted like this you may have to do some clever preg_replace